# Access Denied Importing Certificate on Remote Machine

Tags: powershell, certificate, admin

I'm trying to come up with a way to push out a certificate for install on multiple machines.  The method I came up with is:

```psh
Invoke-Command ServerName {
  Import-Certificate -FilePath "path" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
}
```

And I get:

```
Access is denied. 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified (:) [Import-Certificate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID : System.Exception,Microsoft.CertificationServices.Commands.ImportCertificateCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ServerName
```

I'm running my local PowerShell as administrator, and my account is an administrator on the target machine.  And I have verified that I can install certificates.

Comment: What is the actual path to the certificate file? Also, are you in a domain environment? If so, group policies might be a better option.

Comment: I am in a domain environment, but I don't have access to Group Policy.  My team is responsible for Certs but have limited access to tools like that.  The path is a UNC path to the file on my desktop, which checks out.

Comment: You most likely ran into the so-called [2nd hop problem](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx). As for pushing out certificates with group policies: I'd recommend talking to your domain admins. Depending on how frequently this needs to be done establishing a workflow might be worthwhile. It would give both you and them better control over certificate distribution.

Comment: What is the version of the PS on both servers?

Comment: If I log onto the target machine and run the code in the {}'s it works fine, but only if I Run As Administrator. So while on my machine I'm launching as Administrator, it doesn't seem to be translating that over to the target.  That Second Hop thing might work, but I intend to be distributing these certs to a large number of machines.  Is the Credential delegation temporary or will it be permanent to all servers I do this with?

Comment: AFAIK the setting is persistent and must be disabled if you don't want it to be permanent.